# Software to analyze task duration and progress

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that has information of 50+ tasks that take place, their start and stop time. They all have a very different begin time, end time and duration. I have to go through each task manually and visually to find this information at this moment. I am looking for a software that I can review specific time to see which tasks and how many tasks are in progress.

Does anyone have recommendation on how I can use Excel, or any other software to achieve what I want to do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Something like MS Project then?

Comment: Google "data mining tool" and there are many programs that can do even more complicated task

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think i have a good starting point with MS Project and Data mining tool
here is a link I will use, and start testing some of the free tools out there
http://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/top-free-data-mining-software/

Comment: You can also use https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/ for data analysis.

Comment: Since you already have Excel, do it in there. Start building the appropriate columns with formulas, then if you are stuck, ask your question at [SU].

Answer (score 0):

Using Excel and assuming you have rows for each task and columns for start time and duration you can have a cell for time now and a column for due in progress. Use a formula for the cells in that column of =if(and(*starttime* < *timenow*, *endtime* > *timenow*), 1, 0) with absolute reference for *timenow* and the appropriate cell pointers for start & end times - you can then sum the in progress column for the number of tasks in progress and use conditional highlights for showing which.